# How does this each method work?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code and I was wondering if anyone could help explain how it works.

I have a very basic class

```
class Configs
  attr_accessor :config_files

  def initialize(*config_files)
    @config_files = config_files
  end
end


configs = Configs.new('config.txt','config1.txt')

configs.each { |c| puts c }

config.txt
config1.txt
=> ['config.txt', 'config1.txt']
```

if `configs` is a `Configs` instance, how does the `each` method find the array inside?

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? Just this snippet in isolation on Ruby 1.9.3 doesn't work.

Comment: Did you copy/paste incorrectly?  When I run your example, I see https://gist.github.com/davidann/7012132

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake by using Rubymine's IRB console. After a reload the each method was still working because I implemented my own previously, and just hacking around I removed it and it still worked. I wasnt sure how that was possible which led me to ask the question. After seeing all the replies I completely killed the process and the each method was gone. Thanks for all the thoughtful and timely replies though, love this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as displayed:

```
class Configs
  attr_accessor :config_files

  def initialize(*config_files)
    @config_files = config_files
  end
end

configs = Configs.new('config.txt','config1.txt')

configs.each { |c| puts c }
# ~> -:12:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for #<Configs:0x007f8a41899810> (NoMethodError)
```

You'd need to change it to:

```
configs.config_files.each { |c| puts c }
# >> config.txt
# >> config1.txt
```

`configs` is your instance of the `Configs` class. (Actually you should call it `Config`, as a class is more likely to be a single occurrence of something, and `config` as a single instance of that class.)

`configs` has an instance variable `@config_files`, which is an array. There is a `config_files` accessor to it that returns that instance variable.

Using `configs.config_files` returns a reference to `@config_files`, which *does* have an `each` method, because it's an array.

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse you use `*config_files`,which created the array,when the line `configs = Configs.new('config.txt','config1.txt')` executed. Your `Configs.new` called actaully `Class#new`,which also called you `#initialize` method,where you used *splatted argument*.One simple demo

```
*a = 1,2,3
a # => [1, 2, 3]
```

**Corrcted code**

```
class Configs
  attr_accessor :config_files

  def initialize(*config_files)
    @config_files = config_files
  end
end


configs = Configs.new('config.txt','config1.txt')

configs.config_files.each {|c| puts c}

# >> config.txt
# >> config1.txt
```

Comment: This is not the question. He's asking how come `Configs` has `each` method.